# Customize button SingIn with Google Account firebase

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-identity

I've been trying to change the alignment of google login button that comes in Firebase.

```
for (int i = 0; i < signInButton.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = signInButton.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof TextView) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) v;
            tv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Also I tried to take the padding by xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button_facebook_login"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp" />
```

also thought to create a class that extends the SignInButton class, however it is final and lets not be inherited.

 All code I've ever seen or tried always use the the same result:[image]

I would like to align the text more to the left button, I could get closest to the icon.